# Не находит модуль после запуска через Parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js

При попытки запустить в консоли через parcel index.html появляется данная проблема

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lucck\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\bin\cli.js'

←[90m  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)←[39m

←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)←[39m

←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m

←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {

code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,

requireStack: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем , я не знаю как это работает и почему, но для того чтобы решить эту проблему мне понадобилось удалить папку npm , которую вы найдете по адресу
C:\Users"Your Username"\AppData\Roaming\npm
Видимо при первой установке Parcel что то было не так....